# Excel Row Mixup

Tags: excel, vba

To start with, I have never seen anything like this in 15 years of Excel programming.

On a lighter note I feel that this particular Excel File is Haunted :P

On a serious note, I really can't understand what's going on.

**Problem**

The code (I didn't write it) runs and hides the rows based on a condition. When you click on any cell except in column C in row `59`, it shows that it is from row `58`. Only in cell C, it shows the correct address.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**What have I tried?**

1. First I thought it is a `ScreenUpdating` issue but as you can see the code, that this is ruled out.
2. I manually went into all those cells starting from Col A to Col D and in Immediate window typed `?Activecell.Row`. I got `58,59,58,58`
3. Checked Google if anyone has ever experienced this kind of issue. But couldn't find a single instance! I don't know what else could be the issue.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim i, j, k, lastrow As Long
    Dim finlast As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Income_Disc
    lastrow = Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
    finlast = Sheets("Financial_Disc").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Value + 1
    
    If Target.Column = 9 And Target.Row = 1 Then
        'Unhide Rows if I1 is double clicked
        Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Rows("1:65536").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        If Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row < lastrow Then
            If Target.Column = 9 Then
                'Hide Rows
                For j = Target.Row To lastrow
                    If Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("B" & CStr(j + 1)) <> "" Then
                        'Hide Rows
                        Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("A" & CStr(j)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        'Hide Rows
                        Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("A" & CStr(j)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("A8:A65536").ClearContents
    
    For i = 8 To lastrow
        If Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("A" & CStr(i)).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            If Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("B" & CStr(i)) <> "" Then
                Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("A" & CStr(i)) = ""
            End If
        Else
            If Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("B" & CStr(i)) <> "" Then
                Sheets("Financial_Disc1").Range("A" & CStr(i)) = finlast
                finlast = finlast + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Misc Points**

As you can see this file has columns in reverse because it is from one of my client in Saudi Arabia.

**My Question**

Can anyone see what could be the problem? Or I should simply dismiss it as a "Rare" bug?

Comment: Do you have any merged cells?

Comment: Gary's Student! You are a star! Post that as an answer. Feeling stupid as why didn't I check that!

Comment: It is nothing compared to the help you gave me with the *Name Box* issue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check the row for **merged** cells - traversing them can cause row "shifts"

Comment: @SiddharthRout  See my comment on your post.

Comment: Saw that but seriously, I should have thought of this! I guess at 3:26 AM my brain cells give up :|

Comment: @SiddharthRout  An easy thing to miss since most of us avoid merged cells like the plague!

Comment: Happens to all of us Sid!